# Сложение временных интервалов Period

Tags: java

Приведенный метод возвращает нулевой интервал, хотя расчет периодов правильный подскажите в чем ошибка.

```
private Period kavendarVisl(DefaultTableModel dtm)
    {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
        Period period = Period.ZERO;
        Period smalPeriod;
        for (int row=0;row<dtm.getRowCount();row++)
        {
            LocalDate ld1=LocalDate.parse(dtm.getValueAt(row,0).toString(),formatter);
            LocalDate ld2 = LocalDate.now();
            if (!dtm.getValueAt(row,1).toString().equals(""))
            {
                ld2=LocalDate.parse(dtm.getValueAt(row,1).toString(),formatter);
            }
            smalPeriod = Period.between(ld1,ld2);
            period.plus(smalPeriod);
            System.out.println(smalPeriod.getYears() + " - " + smalPeriod.getMonths());
        }
        System.out.println(period.getYears() +" - " +period.getMonths());
        return period;
    }
```

Comment: Вы дебагом проходились? Что в `LocalDate ld1=LocalDate.parse(dtm.getValueAt(row,0).toString(),formatter);`? Что в `ld2=LocalDate.parse(dtm.getValueAt(row,1).toString(),formatter);`? И тому подобное.

Comment: Я думаю period = period.plus(smalPeriod); это решение ld1 и ld2 корректны, smalPeriod тоже корректно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

period = period.plus(smalPeriod);